# Unity firebase bug in changing type of value in foreach

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase realtime database for ranking system in my game.
But everytime I try to change the type of value from Datasnapshot's child, it seems to get out of foreach

```
string cashierChild = "score_cashier";

FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").OrderByChild(cashierChild).LimitToLast(10)
    .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed To Load");
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            int rank = 0;
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            foreach (var item in snapshot.Children)
            {
                rank = rank + 1;
                Debug.Log("Rank: " + rank + ", nickname: " + item.Child("nickname").Value + ", score: " + item.Child(cashierChild).Value);
                Debug.Log((int)item.Child(cashierChild).Value);
            }
        }

    });
```

result of above code

[image: withTheCode]

it prints whole ranking definitely really well when I didn't call below code

```
Debug.Log((int)item.Child(cashierChild).Value);
```

withoutTheCode

[image]

So I though it's because of type casting like (string) or (int)

Comment: to really compare it you might have to rather use `Debug.Log(item.Child(cashierChild).Value);` and see what this gives you. Also note that firebase values can be of type `string`, `long`, `bool`, `double` ... no `int`. You might get an Expection when trying to parse an incorrect value to `int` and an OverflowException when trying to parse a too huge `long` value to `int`

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're asking. Can you add a single question to your post? Also: please show the JSON that you're querying (as text, no screenshot please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @derHugo @Frankvanpuffelen I resolved the problem using other way casting type!!!
`(string)Convert.ChangeType(item.Child("nickname").Value, typeof(string));`
Thank you for your comments!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem using other way for typecasting.
`(string)Convert.ChangeType(item.Child("nickname").Value, typeof(string));`